# parsing arrays using foreach

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array in the form

```
$array = array(
    name => array (
        [0] => peter,
        [1] => george,
        [2] => sarah
    ),
    age => array(
        [0] =>1,
        [1] =>2,
        [2] =>3
    )
)
```

I want to parse it out into a table but when I use a foreach loop I can't seem to get it to output properly.

If I use

```
foreach($array[name] as $name){
    foreach($array[age] as $age{

        echo $name.$age;
    }
}
```

sort of thing then it just outputs the name with each age and then moves to the next name and then does all 3 ages and then the final age..

I want:

Name1 Age1
Name2 Age2
Name3 Age3

Comment: Your `array` 'age' is not inside array 'name' is it? So your `foreach` loop is wrong.

Comment: this is a poor data structure. Instead of separate name and age arrays, you should have array([0] => array(name=>peter, age=>1), [1] => array(name=>george, age=>2), ...)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($array['name'] as $iKey => $name){

echo $name.$array['age'][$iKey];

}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
foreach (array_keys($array['name']) as $key) {
    echo $array['name'][$key] . $array['age'][$key];
}
```

Basically, get the sub-array keys from one of your "main" arrays, then use that key inside the loop to extract whatever data you need from the two child arrays.

You can find more detailed information on `array_keys` [**here**](https://www.php.net/array_keys) on official documentation.

Answer (score 1):

```
$array = array(
    'name' => array(
    0 => 'peter',
    1 => 'george',
    2 => 'sarah'
    ),
    'age' => array(
    0 =>'1',
    1 =>'2',
    2 =>'3'
    )
);

foreach($array['name'] as $key => $value)
{
    echo 'Name: ' . $value . ' - Age: ' . $array['age'][$key].'<br />';
}
```

Edit: Oh, too late :)

Answer (score 0):

Use while insted:

```
$i=0;
$len=count($array['name']);
while($i<$len){
   echo $array['name'][$i].$array['age'][$i];
   ++$i;
}
```

Use pre-calculations, set the maximum value for your loop before and not in the loop.

See the follwing article for micro optimization tips http://labs.phurix.net/posts/50-php-optimisation-tips-revisited

Comment: This is assuming the length is known to be 3.

Comment: while($i < count($array))

Comment: See my update for the length. It is better to count before looping for optimization purpose.

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($array['name']); $i++) {    
   echo $array['name'][$i].$array['age'][$i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to your question:

```
<?php
$array = array(
"name" => array (
0 => "peter",
1 => "george",
2 => "sarah"
),
"age" => array(
0 =>1,
1 =>2,
2 =>3
)
);
$name = $array['name'];
$age = $array['age'];


for($i=0;$i<count($name);$i++)
{
 echo $name[$i].' '.$age[$i].' ';
}
?>
```